# How can i add TFS in andorid studio 3.4?

Tags: android, tfs

https://medium.com/@gizembusraturan/android-studio-team-foundation-server-plugin-9783d65f0b9c

Based on this tutorial,I tried to add Visual Studio Team Services in my android studio version 3.4
But i didn't find this Visual Studio Team Services  in my plugin
[image]
how can I add TFS in my android studio.
Last time I use git but now need to use TFS in company

Comment: you can have a look at this youtube link-:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lxp8G-8WZU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Team Services is not available under IntelliJ IDEA .
SO I try to use TFS plugin,it work fine for android studio